# How to change a String in a JTextArea - Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm about to make a program where if you click a button it will show some text... But i don't know how to change the string after i have set the string. Here is the code i have right now.

```
//Text Area to "Copy"
String output = "";
JTextArea TArea = new JTextArea(output);
TArea.setBounds(200, 72, 177, 296);
panel.add(TArea);


//When press the button "Generate"
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        String output = "Hello World";
        TArea.setBounds(200, 72, 177, 296);
    }
});
```

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

> But i don't know how to change the string after i have set the string

```
textArea.setText(...);
```

will reset the text

```
textArea.append(...);
```

will add text to the end of the text area.

Other thoughts:

1. I suggest you read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics of using Swing.
2. Don't use setBounds(..). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The tutorial has plenty of examples of using the layout managers.
3. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions and don't make up your own. Any tutorial or text book will follow the conventions.